# Can all fuses be pulled by force?

Tags: fuse, fuse-panel

[image: Close Fuse Box]

[image: the second pic shows a view of the screw underneath the fuse that i was referring to.]

Here is a pic of my cars fuse box.  Sometimes when Im pulling it feels like something may be screwed down underneath and I may snap it.

I know that all the small fuses and medium see through box fuses can be pulled without any problem.
I've also managed to remove the big black boxes without any problem.

Will the coloured boxes also come out in the same way?

You can see I have highlighted one fuse in red bottom left positioned diagonally.  This is a 120a fuse for the battery.  I was trying to remove it however it seems very tight, i noticed some screws underneath it on some white plastic, would this need to be unscrewed first?  I have added another picture which I think you can see the screw in.

Also I have highlighted some cartridges in the top in red, what are these and do they all pull out just like any normal fuse?

Comment: Circled in Red (top of box) are not fuses, they do not appear in the lid diagram.

Comment: Lower red is a big fuse with large terminals and fit very tight in the connectors because they carry so much current, I have broke a few trying to remove.

Comment: What vehicle is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 120A fuse may well be held in with a couple of screws.

Alternatively, in the bottom picture it looks like there may be two clips on the ends which you have to prise back with thin screwdriver blades to remove it. It will clip back into place automatically when you replace it.

The main problem with a row of fuses like you have at the top of the picture is that there is nothing to get hold of to pull on.

Try removing the other fuses around them to get better access. You might then be able to prise up one end from the bottom, with a thin screwdriver blade.

To remove one blown fuse from the middle of the top row, just start with whichever one wants to come out easiest, and work your way in towards the one you want.